# Is there a limit to the number and/or the amount of bounties that can be awarded in a specific time-frame

Tags: support, bounty

As per my question: Is there a limit to the number and/or the amount of bounties that can be awarded during a specific time-frame?

I noticed that all of a sudden the "Start a bounty" (or whatever the specific wording is) has disappeared when I go to a question.

Comment: Is this true for _recent_ questions, or all questions (including older ones)? A question must be two days old before it is eligible for bounties. I think you can only place three bounties at a time. See the help center: [What is a bounty?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: @Max Thanks for the link. You are right, only three at a time.

Comment: I've read your bounty texts, and I'm somewhat confused. If you want to bounty away most of your reputation, that's okay (as long as you chose worthy targets for the bounties), but I don't see how that decision would be connected to receiving a downvote on a question.

Comment: If you prefer to participate here with a lower reputation, that's entirely up to you. I just hope it's not a rash decision that you may regret later. But if you started such an endeavour before, it's probably not rash. However, since the way in which one can participate on the network is tied to the reputation one has, please think carefully about whether you really want to lose privilege X (close voting, editing, commenting, whatever is important for you) before placing a bounty that would push your reputation below that privilege level.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Hope you hadn't read my prior comments in response to yours. No excuses - but I'm 72 and a bit forgetful. Regardless, my intention is to opt out of the vote accumulation dynamic. I had initially thought to request my vote count reduced to around 1000, so I could maintain functionality. Then I thought I would give them away. Then I realized that at 3×100 at 3/week it will take a long time. I do recognize the value of votes - indicating the merits of questions and answers to users. Yet for my own participation here,

Comment: @DanielFischer I am intent on doing this. In fact, you would do me a favor to reduce my reputation to 1900 and I will dispose of the rest keeping me above 1000. If you can  - please consider this my formal request to do so. As always, I appreciate your generous participation here. Best regards,

Comment: Reducing the reputation of users is not something moderators can do. Technically, some employees of the company would be able to, but I'm sure such a request would be declined. If you want to reduce your reputation faster, you would have to award higher bounties. One can award bounties up to 500 points, and with a couple of such bounties, it wouldn't take you very long.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, you have [three active bounties](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12802/andrew?tab=bounties). That's the maximum, according to the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> - Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.

Comment: Saw your bio. You are probably familiar with Wolfgang Pauli's remark distinguishing himself from physicist Wolfgang Paul: he's the real one.